# Background Image fit options?

Tags: html, css

I have applied background image option for my application its working good.but i want to fix the background image use fit options like fill,fit,strech etc...how to apply that options for my application depend on user selected options.

code :

Comment: Please add your code.

Comment: @(Html.Kendo().DropDownList()
                                                    .Name("infobgimagefitType")
                                           .Events(ev => ev.Open("positionDropDown"))
                                            .BindTo(inSisEnums.Enums.EnumToSelectList(typeof(inSisEnums.InfobgimageFitType)))
                                            .SelectedIndex(((int)ViewBag.Settings.Imagefittype))
                                            .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width:90px;font-size:small;float:right" })

                        )

Comment: i want to working functionality as like windows desktop image

Answer (score 0):

Create CSS classses for fill, Stretch and fit.
Add them to the background div using addClass or toggle using toggleClass through JS.

```
.fill {
    background: url('image.jpg');
    background-repeat: repeat;
}

.stretch{
    background: url('image.jpg');
    background-size: cover;
}
```